# How to get NFT's transfer history like polygonscan

Tags: polygon, history, transfer, nft, opensea

I minted my NFT through my own smart contract successfully. But I don't know how to get my NFT's transfer history like polygonscan do. Is there any API or functions to get NFT history?
Some documents said that I should make a event listener which detect the owner is changed. Is it work even I sell my NFT on my own web site and opensea?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific marketplace or website. But generally, most marketplaces invoke the `transferFrom()` function on the collection contract during the sale, effectively emitting the `Transfer` event, that you can handle in your offchain app.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried the Transfer Event and it work really well!!